# How to enable automatic background refresh in Excel with closed workbook when connected to external database, such as Oracle?

Tags: excel, database, oracle, background, refresh

I want to have automatic background refresh when the workbook is closed. I've set a testing time to update (see the screenshot below), but it never works.

[image]

[image]

FYI, I'm trying to refresh data from the external Oracle Database. When I refresh data myself clicking on Refresh button, it works perfect. But it doesn't refresh automatically in the background when file is closed, what could be the reason and is there any workaround to solve that?

Comment: The file won't refresh unless it's open. You could schedule to open and refresh programmatically tho.

Comment: Are you sure, you query an Oracle database? The screenshot does not look like this, it uses provider "Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb" which is a Microsoft Power Query OLE DB provider.